# How to extract private class members with doxygen?

Tags: xml, doxygen

i want to document a class including its private members using doxygen.
This is my class definition "AshtechAsioNode.h"

```
    /** @file AshtechAsioNode.h  */

/*

#ifndef CATKIN_WS_ASHTECHASIONODE_H
#define CATKIN_WS_ASHTECHASIONODE_H

//some generically useful stuff to include...
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <std_msgs/Empty.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/NavSatFix.h>
#include <medusa_msgs/mLatLonPos.h>
#include <diagnostic_msgs/DiagnosticArray.h>
#include <medusa_gimmicks_library/MedusaGimmicks.h>
#include <nmeaSerial.h>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <std_msgs/Int8.h>
#include <std_msgs/Bool.h>

#include <ros/ros.h> //ALWAYS need to include this 

/**
* \class AshtechAsioNode
* \brief This class represents a GPS.
* \details Add class description. Control 0.
*/
class AshtechAsioNode {

    // #############################
    // @.@ Public methods
    // #############################
    public:
        
        // #############################
        // @.@ Constructor
        // #############################
        // "main" will need to instantiate two ROS nodehandles, then pass it to the constructor
        AshtechAsioNode(ros::NodeHandle* nodehandle, ros::NodeHandle *nodehandle_private);

        // #############################
        // @.@ Destructor
        // #############################
        ~AshtechAsioNode();

        
        /// Set frequency of the node. The frequency is defined by a ROS parameter.
        double nodeFrequency();

    // #############################
    // @.@ Private methods
    // #############################
    
    private:
        
        /// Node handler for node management.
        ros::NodeHandle nh_; ///< we will need this, to pass between "main" and constructor

        /// Node handler for extra layer of namespace resolution. Initialized with '~' parameter.
        ros::NodeHandle nh_p_; ///< we will need this, to pass between "main" and constructor

        // some objects to support subscriber and publishers, these will be set up within the class constructor, hiding the ugly details

        /// Subscribers
        // #####################
        // @.@ Subscribers
        // #####################
        
        ros::Subscriber sub_corrections_; ///< Subscribes to reconfiguration commands.
        ros::Subscriber sub_conf_; ///< Subscribes to $PASHR strings used to write to the device.
        ros::Subscriber sub_reset_; ///< Subscribes to the 'reset' topic.

        ///Publishers
        // #####################
        // @.@ Publishers
        // #####################
        ros::Publisher pub_corrections_;
        ros::Publisher pub_raw_;
        ros::Publisher pub_gps_;
        ros::Publisher pub_diag_;
        ros::Publisher pub_gps_NavSat_;

        std::vector<std::string> p_config_list_;

        nmeaSerial serial_port_;

        std::string p_sPORT_;
        int p_BAUDRATE_;
        int p_RTK_port_;
        int fd_udp_socket_;
        bool rtk_flag_;

        std::map<int, int> baudrate_table_;


        // #######################
        // @.@ Timer
        // #######################
        ros::Timer timer_;

        // ####################################################################################################################
        // member variable: better than using globals; convenient way to pass data from a subscriber to other member functions
        // member variables will retain their values even as callbacks come and go
        // ####################################################################################################################

        // +.+ Parameters from Yaml
        // always p_paraName -> Example: double p_ku;

        // +.+ Handy variables
        // Example double var_temp_x, var_temp_y;

        // +.+ Problem variables
        // Example: double x_state, y_state;


        // #######################################################################################
        // @.@ Encapsulation the gory details of initializing subscribers, publishers and services
        // #######################################################################################
        void initializeSubscribers(); ///< hhhhhhh;
        void initializePublishers();
        void initializeTimer();
        void loadParams();

        void reporting(const ros::Time t);
        void initializeBaudrateTable();
        void configureGPS();
        int openGPS();
        int UDPSocket(unsigned port);


        // #######################################################################################
        // @.@ Callbacks declaration
        // #######################################################################################
        void dropoutCallback(const ros::TimerEvent& event);
        void rawCallback(const std::string& msg);
        void resetCallback(const std_msgs::Empty& msg);
        void confCallback(const std_msgs::String& str);
        void pashrCallback(const std::vector<std::string>& tokens);
        void correctionsCallback(const std_msgs::String& ptr);
};
#endif //CATKIN_WS_ASHTECHASIONODE_H
```

This is part of my doxygen configuration file

```
    EXTRACT_ALL            = NO
    
    # If the EXTRACT_PRIVATE tag is set to YES, all private members of a class will
    # be included in the documentation.
    # The default value is: NO.
    
    EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
    
    # If the EXTRACT_PACKAGE tag is set to YES, all members with package or internal
    # scope will be included in the documentation.
    # The default value is: NO.
    
    EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
    
    # If the EXTRACT_STATIC tag is set to YES, all static members of a file will be
    # included in the documentation.
    # The default value is: NO.
    
    EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
    
    # If the EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES tag is set to YES, classes (and structs) defined
    # locally in source files will be included in the documentation. If set to NO,
    # only classes defined in header files are included. Does not have any effect
    # for Java sources.
    # The default value is: YES.
    
    EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
    
    # This flag is only useful for Objective-C code. If set to YES, local methods,
    # which are defined in the implementation section but not in the interface are
    # included in the documentation. If set to NO, only methods in the interface are
    # included.
    # The default value is: NO.
```

Notice how I included `/** @file AshtechAsioNode.h  */` in the beginning of the file and set extract_private to yes. But it only outputs the public members to the documentation.Don't care about the comments itself or the indentation. Its just dummy comments and just a copy to experiment with doxygen (first time).

Comment: Which version of doxygen ? I do see the documentation for e.g `nh_` (I just set `EXTRACT_ALL=NO` and `EXTRACTPRIVATE=YES`. Note: the `/** @file AshtechAsioNode.h  */` would be better as `/** @file */`, when changing the name of the file this would give less problems.

Comment: @albert Its the latest version (1.8.20). I also have EXTRACT_ALL  = NO and EXTRACT_PRIVATE = YES. What could it be? Whats your doxygen version?

I type in the terminal:

doxygen doxy_config

Where doxy_config is the doxygen config file in the current directory

Comment: I got a few more versions, but I tested it with 1.8.20 and the current master. Can you give the command `doxygen -x doxy_config` and postt the output in the question? Please also complete the `class` as at the moment at least the closing `}` is missing.

Comment: Do you want to generate the xml output (though I see `nh_` here also i.e. in xml/class_ashtech_asio_node.xml)? or the HTML output?

Comment: @albert I want to generate the xml output. Correction the version is 1.8.13. doxygen -x doxy_config its not a valid option. Edited the question with the full class definition.

Comment: the `-x` is indeed not a valid option it was added in a newer version (1.8.13 is already a bit older December, 2016), so I would certainly advise to upgrade. I still see the `nh_` in the mentioned xml file.